# launch4j and external files on classpath

Tags: java, gradle, launch4j

I am working on a java application that uses gradle with the launch4j plugin to create a windows exe wrapper. I am required to write a 'help' framework to display help documentation to the user from within the application, and I am unsure of a method to do this, given that the only items in the classpath are the various jar files in the lib folder.

I had planned on making HTML documents for the help files, and loading these documents in the GUI through the JavaFX WebView control. With this in mind, I have the following directory structure in my application distribution:

```
root
  |
  + config
  + help
  + lib
  - Application.exe
  - LICENSE
```

Assuming I can continue to do this as I had planned, how might I get the help and config folders into the classpath for launch4j, using only gradle config scripts (not manually editing the launch4j.xml file). If this can't be done, is there another recommended way I can include external files on the classpath so I can safely reference them using `ClassLoader.getSystemResource()`?

Answer (score 0):

You should put your `help` (and `config`) directories as resources into the JAR. To do so with Gradle, move these directories to the `src/main/resources` directory. From there you can access their contents via `getClass().getResource()` / `getClass().getResourceAsStream()`.

Comment: Adding the config folder as a resource in the jar is not acceptable, as those files would need to be editable by the user